# Android caching library which provides way of deleting cache

Tags: android, caching

I'm trying to  find androd caching library which provides ways of invalidating cache.
Example, I call web service to get some object. I want to cache that object (the way of implementing of cache is not important to me). What is important is that when I use web service to update that object I want to invalidate cache. I think it is very common requirement, but cannot find any good library which does this.
https://github.com/vincentbrison/android-easy-cache seems popular and feature ritch but how come there is no something like `cache.remove("some-key")`

Comment: Don't understand the problem, putting a new value with the same key will update the existing value.

Comment: Ofcourse, but I need to have some global variable which keeps record if object with some key needs to be updated. For example inside updateCar method I need to have global variable like "CarInvalidateCache=true", then inside GetCar method I need to check that variable to know do I have to call web service. cache.remove("Car-cache") somewhere after updateCar method would be much more convenient.

Comment: Global variables can be destroyed by android, but I'm not sure what will  happen with cache. I don't want to give user data which is not more valid. cache.remove("car-cache") sound to me much less error prone.

Comment: For example, I call updateCar method then put this statement Globals.needInvaliadateCarCache=true, then user closes app, eventually android destroys variables, but there is possibility that cache still sticks around (it's moment of death is not consistent with variables),then user visits app again (Globals.needInvalidateCarCache is now by default false ofcourse) and user gets cached data